# sudo apt-get update errors: how do I clean up my MariaDB installation?

Tags: apt, software-updates, mariadb, synaptic, ppa

Linux Mint 18.3 (based on Ubuntu Xenial).

I have looked at the other questions here, but I still don't know where to start about cleaning up my package lists and specifically MariaDB. Any links to somewhere I can read a bit more about managing these lists and the dos and don'ts of them would be good.

In particular I'd like to know just one thing from the output below: what should I do about my MariaDB (MySQL) installation?

When I try to find out my mysql and mysqld versions I get the following

```
mikeM17A ~ $  mysql --version
mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.2.16-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.2
mike@M17A ~ $  mysqld --version
mysqld  Ver 10.2.16-MariaDB-10.2.16+maria~xenial for debian-linux-gnu on x86_64 (mariadb.org binary distribution)
```

in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ I have two files that appear to be involved in this MySQL problem: MariaDB101.list and MariaDB102.list. The latter, for example, contains just one line:

```
deb https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena main
```

Is the idea to delete these? And then should I maybe install the MariaDB available in Synaptic (10.2.27)? Trouble is there are tens of packages with the word "mariadb" in them... I don't know which to install.

If I do that, will they somehow get installed "over" the existing MariaDB installation?

Any other comments on this output from `sudo apt-get update` would be greatly appreciated.

```
mike@M17A ~ $  sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 http://ppa.launchpad.net/adabbas/1stppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                              
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/alessandro-strada/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                              
Hit:4 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_10.x xenial InRelease                                                               
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                                   
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/bit-team/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                    
Hit:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease                                                           
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/cwchien/gradle/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                     
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease                                                        
Get:12 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease [2,591 B]                                                      
Hit:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                    
Hit:14 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease                                                        
Ign:15 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena InRelease                                              
Ign:16 http://packages.linuxmint.com sylvia InRelease                                                                     
Hit:17 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jeffreyratcliffe/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                              
Ign:18 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena InRelease                                              
Hit:19 https://dl.winehq.org/wine-builds/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                          
Ign:20 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena Release                                                
Hit:21 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                               
Hit:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-sheldon/deepspeech/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
Get:23 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease [3,316 B]                                                           
Ign:24 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena Release                                                
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/michael-sheldon/gst-deepspeech/ubuntu xenial InRelease                          
Get:26 http://packages.linuxmint.com sylvia Release [24.2 kB]                                                             
Ign:27 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages                                    
Hit:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                              
Ign:29 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages                                     
Hit:30 http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                     
Ign:31 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main all Packages                                      
Ign:32 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB                                 
Hit:33 http://ppa.launchpad.net/qos/pulseaudio-dlna/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                               
Ign:34 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en                                    
Hit:35 http://ppa.launchpad.net/rolfbensch/sane-git/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                               
Ign:36 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages                      
Ign:37 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages                                     
Hit:38 http://ppa.launchpad.net/stefansundin/truecrypt/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                            
Err:12 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                                                                
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B8EC3BAABDC4346
Ign:39 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages                                      
Ign:40 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB                                 
Hit:41 http://ppa.launchpad.net/team-xbmc/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                     
Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en                                    
Hit:43 http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                                    
Get:44 http://packages.linuxmint.com sylvia Release.gpg [819 B]                                                           
Ign:27 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages                                    
Hit:45 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thomas.tsai/ubuntu-tuxboot/ubuntu xenial InRelease                                        
Ign:29 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages                                     
Ign:31 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main all Packages 
Ign:32 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:34 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Ign:36 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
Ign:37 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Hit:46 http://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/dbms/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:23 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Ign:39 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:40 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Ign:27 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
Ign:29 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:32 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:34 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Ign:36 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
Ign:37 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:39 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:40 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Ign:27 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
Ign:29 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:32 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:34 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Ign:36 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
Ign:37 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:39 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:40 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Ign:27 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
Ign:29 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:32 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:34 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Ign:36 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
Ign:37 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:39 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:40 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Err:27 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:29 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:32 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:34 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Err:36 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:37 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main i386 Packages
Ign:39 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main all Packages
Ign:40 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en_GB
Ign:42 https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena/main Translation-en
Fetched 30.9 kB in 2s (14.3 kB/s)
Reading package lists... Done
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B8EC3BAABDC4346
W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
W: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Failed to fetch https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable/dists/stable/InRelease  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B8EC3BAABDC4346
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.2/ubuntu/dists/serena/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-i386/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en_GB) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> W: The repository 'https://mirrors.evowise.com/mariadb/repo/10.1/ubuntu serena Release' does not have a Release file.
> ```

Remove the repository with `serena` codename (Mint 18.01), the repository doesn't support the `serena` codname.

> ```
> W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:2 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list:3
> ```

Check the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/additional-repositories.list` you have configured the same repository multiples times and remove the duplicate entries.

> ```
> W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4B8EC3BAABDC4346
> ```

You need to download the gpg key , [see Manually adding the Opera APT repository](https://deb.opera.com/manual.html)

```
wget -qO - https://deb.opera.com/archive.key | sudo apt-key add -
```

> ```
> W: GPG error: http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4773BD5E130D1D45
>
>  W: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
> ```

You need to add the gpg key for [spotify repo](https://www.spotify.com/us/download/linux/):

```
curl -sS https://download.spotify.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | sudo apt-key add -
```

Then run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt autoremove
```

Comment: Thanks very much! I followed all these instructions and now when I do `sudo apt-get update` I just get "Hits" an "Gets" (and one "Ign"). Your answer provides a key to help me research this subject more, i.e. exactly how this package list business works, whether I am now properly configured for MySQL/MariaDB. I presume some of your answer is down to general Nixcraft, and some to searching on the basis of the wording of the errors/warnings produced. Really helpful.